# QGIS Automatically Converts UTC Date-Time to Local?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs, datetime

I imported a WFS layer from a geoserver  into QGIS and also into a web service that is based on Cesium.  The geoserver fetches the data from Elastic search and serves it out as WFS.  The date-time attribute of the data stored in Elastic Search is in UTC.  The web service (based on Cesium) displays the date-time attribute in UTC, but QGIS displays the same date-time attribute my local time zone.  My local time zone is GMT minus 5 hours.

Example:  A date-time attribute is stored in Elastic Search as ‘2017-12-29 01:10:37.000Z’. The web service displays the date-time as ‘2017-12-29T01:10:37Z’.  The QGIS Identify Results and the QGIS attribute table both display the date-time as ‘2017-12-28T20:10:37’

Including a ‘Z’ in the SQL filter doesn’t seem to make any difference and provides misleading results.  In QGIS, the layer filter date-time = ‘2017-12-28 20:10:37.000Z’ finds the feature, but date-time = ‘2017-12-29 01:10:37.000Z’ does not find the feature.

It seems QGIS is converting the date-time attribute to local time.  I can’t find a preference to override QGIS converting date-time values.  I want the results to be displayed in UTC, not local.  Is there a way to do that in QGIS?

Comment: Have you checked the raw output from GeoServer to be sure that it does not change the times?

Comment: Just checked.  Queried GML shows UTC time coming from the geoserver.

Comment: What happens if you save the GML from the server into a file and open that with QGIS? Is it still changing the time to local?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I made http calls to the geoserver for the exact same feature and requested returns to be in different formats:  GML3, CSV, and JSON.  All three returned UTC date-times.  In QGIS, the same feature, when viewed in the "Identify Results" panel shows the date-time in local time instead of UTC time.  I want UTC time instead of local time.

Answer (score 1):

If you save your time as QDatetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, QDatetime.timeSpec(1)), it will retain your UTC time. However, if you supply a metadata.extents() to the layer, it appears to undo your temporal timeSpec(). This appears to be a bug in Qgis handling of metadata. I am experiencing the same results.